# ms-Access VBA doesn't make new records and rewrite old records

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

I have a table with over 3 Million records and some fields. which looks like this:

| MeliDrv | NameDriver | Mobile | Pelak | Serial_Mashin | Cardid_T | BAG | MaghPRV | MabshPRV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | John Doe | 099999 | 124A4 | 55 | 2541235 | sth | AZ | CA |
| 1111111 | John Doe | 099999 | 124A4 | 55 | 2541235 | sth | AZ | CA |
| 1111111 | John Doe | 099999 | 124A4 | 55 | 2541235 | sth | AZ | BS |
| 2222222 | Alice Bank | 088888 | 254B7 | 32 | 4587621 | St2 | AZ | CA |
| 2222222 | Alice Bank | 088888 | 254B7 | 32 | 4587621 | St2 | TX | NY |

And what I need is a table made up of this which shows a summary, so I can make a report based on "MaghPRV", "MabshPRV" and "Bag" which show the user that which order "MeliDrv" based on their counts. something like this:

| MeliDrv | NameDriver | Mobile | Pelak | Serial_Mashin | Cardid_T | BAG | MaghPRV | MabshPRV | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111111 | John Doe | 099999 | 124A4 | 55 | 2541235 | sth | AZ | CA | 2 |
| 2222222 | Alice Bank | 088888 | 254B7 | 32 | 4587621 | St2 | AZ | CA | 1 |
| 1111111 | John Doe | 099999 | 124A4 | 55 | 2541235 | sth | AZ | BS | 1 |
| 2222222 | Alice Bank | 088888 | 254B7 | 32 | 4587621 | St2 | TX | NY | 1 |

So, This is routine in excel, but based on large number of recordes (Over 3M) I have to use Access, and i have wrote a VBA code to do this. **The Problem is that I get only one record in final table** and changing the code (like adding .MoveNext and etc) doesn't change that. Also it is very slow and based on my search, there was not a way to do this without recordsets.
Thanks for your help

```
Option Explicit

'------------------Variables----------
Sub MacroTest()
Dim dbData As DAO.Database
Dim lsPrv As Variant
Dim sSQL As String, sSQL2 As String, sSQL3 As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rs2 As DAO.Recordset, rs3 As DAO.Recordset
Dim cnt As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim tmpMELIDRV As Long


'----------------Initialization--------------------
lsPrv = Array("Ardebil", "Esfahan", "Alborz", "Ilam", "E Azarbayjan", "W Azarbayjan", "Bushehr", "Tehran", "Chaharmahal", "S Khorasan", "Razavi Khorasan", "N Khorasan", "Khuzestan", "Zanjan", "Semnan", "Sistan", "Fars", "Ghazvin", "Kordestan", "Kerman", "Kermanshah", "Kohgiluyeh", "Golestan", "Gilan", "Lorestan", "Mazandaran", "Markazi", "Hormozgan", "Hamedan", "Yazd")
Set dbData = CurrentDb

dbData.Execute "CREATE TABLE tblDRV1 (drvID CHAR, drvMobile Char, carID varChar, carType varChar,MaghPrv Char, MabPrv Char, Cnt Integer);"
    'For i = 0 To 30
        'For j = 0 To 30
        i = 1
        j = 1
            sSQL = "Select MELIDRV,MOBILE,PELAK,BAG,MAGHPRV,MABSHPRV From TotQQ Where MABSHPRV='" & lsPrv(i) & "' AND MAGHPRV='" & lsPrv(j) & "';"
            Set rs = dbData.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
            'IF (rs.EOF AND rs.BOF)THen GOTO
            rs.MoveFirst
            tmpMELIDRV = "1"
            While Not (rs.EOF)
                If rs!MELIDRV <> tmpMELIDRV Then
                    sSQL2 = "Select count(*) As Cnt From TotQQ Where MELIDRV='" & rs!MELIDRV & "';"
                    Set rs2 = dbData.OpenRecordset(sSQL2, dbOpenSnapshot)
                    cnt = rs2!cnt
                    'sSQL3 = "INSERT INTO tblDRV1 (drvID,drvMobile,carID,carType,MaghPrv,MabPrv,Cnt) Values ('" & rs!MELIDRV & "','" & rs!MOBILE & "','" & rs!PELAK & "','" & rs!BAG & "','" & rs!MAGHPRV & "','" & rs!MABSHPRV & "','" & rs2!cnt & "');"
                    'dbData.Execute sSQL3
                    Set rs3 = dbData.OpenRecordset("tblDRV1")
                    rs3.AddNew
                    rs3!drvID.Value = rs!MELIDRV
                    rs3!drvMobile.Value = rs!MOBILE
                    rs3!carID.Value = rs!PELAK
                    rs3!carType.Value = rs!BAG
                    rs3!MAGHPRV.Value = rs!MAGHPRV
                    rs3!MABPRV.Value = rs!MABSHPRV
                    rs3!cnt.Value = rs2!cnt
                    rs3.Update
                    rs3.Close
                    tmpMELIDRV = rs!MELIDRV
                    rs.MoveNext
                Else
                    rs.MoveNext
                End If
            Wend
rs.Close
rs2.Close
Set dbData = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you create a query in Access  which does the needed calculation?

Comment: Besides using a query as being the way to do this, it should be noted that you are repeatedly opening and closing a recordset (`Set rs3 = dbData.OpenRecordset("tblDRV1")`) that is based on the whole table. Far better would be just to open it once (`Set rs3=dbData.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblDRV1 WHERE 1=2;")` outside of the loop. The `WHERE 1=2` ensures that it is an empty recordset, so loads faster.

Comment: Take a look at the sample code from this link when you have a chance.

https://www.erlandsendata.no/english/index.php?t=envbadac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Storax said, just use a query.
From your first table, this will create the second table.

```
SELECT      MeliDrv, NameDrive, Mobile, Pelak, Serial_Mashin, 
            Cardid_T, BAG, MaghPRV, MabshPRV, Count(*) AS Count
FROM        TotQQ 
GROUP BY    MeliDrv, NameDrive, Mobile, Pelak, Serial_Mashin, 
            Cardid_T, BAG, MaghPRV, MabshPRV
```

Comment: @Storax.... sorry, I feel your pain when some posts your answer a few minutes earlier.

Comment: Thank you @Darren Bartrup-Cook. It Works. Also thank You @ Storax
I have tried several options for "not making new rows". That is why rs3.close exists. it was not in first edition. but later I changed it. Also I would like to thank for that tip